# Multiple instances of the same android widget: Anyway way to have instance specific preferences?

Tags: android

I am creating a simple Android widget with a typical usecase of having many instances of it running at once.

Using the stock preferencesmanager, it seems each instance of the widget shares the same preferences.

Is there any way to not have this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try overriding `getPreferenceManager()` in your `PreferenceActivity`, and return a custom `PreferenceManager` in which you have overridden `getPreferences()` to return a different `SharedPreferences` object for each app widget. I have not tried this, so I am not completely certain it will work. If it does, and you think of it, comment on this answer to let me know!

Comment: Interesting idea.  I ended up just prefixing preferences with their widget ID - dirty, but a lot of the API docs do it the same way, just took some digging.  See: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/appwidget/ExampleAppWidgetConfigure.html